# Duplicate entry with a one to many relation

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa

In **Contact** class I have

```
Long contactId;

@OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Location> locations;
```

In **Location** class, I have

```
Long locationId;
```

When I try to `init` database, I do

```
INSERT INTO contact(first_name, last_name, contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId) values ('Dan Alvarez',  'Bernal', 5);
INSERT INTO contact_locations(contact_contactId, locations_locationId) values (1, 5);

INSERT INTO contact(first_name, last_name, contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId) values ('Steph', 'Borduas', 5);
INSERT INTO contact_locations(contact_contactId, locations_locationId) values (2, 4);

INSERT INTO contact(first_name, last_name, contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId) values ('Luc', 'La Haye', 5);
INSERT INTO contact_locations(contact_contactId, locations_locationId) values (3, 9);

INSERT INTO contact(first_name, last_name, contact_sub_category_contactSubCategoryId) values ('George', 'Leblond', 5);
INSERT INTO contact_locations(contact_contactId, locations_locationId) values (4, 9);
```

> Duplicate entry '9' for key 'UK_63147bdnwnn3oecl34tlxkkd4' Column
>   count doesn't match value count at row 1

It's like **locations_locationId** can't have same value.

A contact can have many location and a location can many contact.

Don't know if it need to put a many to many relation there, would like to avoid that if i can.

Edit

I tried to use

```
@JoinTable(
        uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"locations_locationId","contact_contactId"})
    )
```

but that create 3 index and don't fixe the problem

Edit 2: with many to many, that work.

Comment: looking at the name for the key, you might have a unique constraint on that column

Comment: Why would you want to avoid a many:many if that is what the business logic calls for? If the relationship isn't many:many then don't model it that way. If it is many:many then model it that way.

Comment: Should this be a Many-To-One relationship (many contacts can be in one location rather than one contact can be in many locations)?

Comment: @JamieD77, if they have one, it's jpa who have created it.